# WebStorm stopped auto importing Angular 4 CLI

Tags: webstorm, angular-cli

As far as I remember, WebStorm usually imports itself all the thing I try to use without importing. However, after few reinstallations it stopped to try import something.

Is there any reslove? I use the latest version of stable WebStorm with standard configuration and Node plugin is enabled. Also `node_modules` is marked as root directory and isn't excluded.

Also, I saw in one video that man just typed in `[(ngModel)]="title"` and it was working. That means that his WebStorm imported needed library for forms.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set your JavaScript library list, by going to

> Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries

Then add your project node_modules directory into the libraries list.

Comment: sorry, but this did not make any change and did not work

Comment: This was exactly my problem, i've searched and searched for this solution.  It's worth noting that it didn't work for me immediately.  After re-indexing (10 minutes or so) it worked.